# Got an error while installing new UI theme shoreditch for civicrm?

Tags: civicrm-home, ui

I was trying to install new UI theme i.e.shoreditch for civicrm.
While installing it gives an error.

[image]

I also tried to change the hostname i.e. localhost to 127.0.0.1 but couldn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure how CiviCRM will understand `drush en` to enable shoreditch extension. Shoreditch extension is under CiviCRM not under Drupal. But there is different drush command to install CiviCRM extensions

1. List CiviCRM extensions

> drush cel

2. Install CiviCRM extension

> drush cei org.civicrm.shoreditch

3. Disabled CiviCRM extension

> drush ced org.civicrm.shoreditch

4. Uninstall CiviCRM extension

> drush ceui org.civicrm.shoreditch

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: I tried first command but got an error. The drush command 'cel' could not be found

Comment: Hoping you are running under drupal directory. If yes can you run drush help en or drush help cel.

Comment: I am in drupal diretory

Comment: What does the drush help en or drush help cel give you

Comment: $ drush help cel
List of CiviCRM extensions enabled.

Examples:
 Standard example                          drush civicrm-ext-list

Aliases: cel

Comment: that means it works (drush cel  or drush civicrm-ext-list )

Comment: yes but it gives me some DB problem

Comment: So this is a different problem. Try checking the CiviCRM logs for more error regarding DB

Comment: Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.

Comment: How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84284/discussion-between-pradeep-nayak-and-dipak-giri).